# Telegram API: getHistory and other methods by GET request?

Tags: php, telegram

I understood that i can send Messages very easy through the Telegram API to a channel/chat:
`https://api.telegram.org/bot{TOKEN}/sendMessage?chat_id={@CHAT_ID}&text={TEXTMESSAGE}`

This is working.

What I don't understand is, how to access the other Api-Methods, for example the `messages.getHistory` method.

For example id like to have this:
`https://api.telegram.org/bot{TOKEN}/messages.getHistory?chat_id={@CHAT_ID}&text={TEXTMESSAGE}`
but this results in 404

Is there a way to make simple GET requests for this?
If not, whats the simplest way to get this info in PHP?

I prefer no libraries/packages, I would like to get the most simple solution without packages / dependencies /installations etc.

Comment: May i ask, where you get those URLs / API Calls from? According to the current official documentation [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) i cannot find this method. AFAIK you are not able to recive the whole chat history, you can store messages which are recieved after the bot is added in your own database.

Comment: That is an MTProto method, not a Bot API one.